# Wordpress and Semantic UI

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm new to Wordpress theme development (although I am not new to frontend development) and I would like some advice on how to use Semantic UI in creating a Wordpress theme. Has anyone here tried doing so from scratch?

I'm having problems getting the dropdown menu to work. There's this weird thing happening that if I make it a fixed menu (adding the fixed class), the dropdowns work, otherwise they don't. I'm thinking that there must be conflicts with other CSS or JS files Wordpress is using, but I am not so sure.
Thank you for any advice and/or help.

Comment: Without JS error messages and code it's not possible to diagnose this. The only thing I can think of is that WordPress uses jQuery in no conflict mode, e.g. `jQuery()` rather than `$()` but that's trivial to work around, e.g. `(function($){ ...}(jQuery))`. You're going to need to add a significant amount of information and code to be able to reproduce and diagnose this. Otherwise the chance it's something in WordPress is extremely low, I would focus debugging efforts elsewhere

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting here. I'm just trying to get a feel of how Wordpress developers do with Semantic UI since there's almost answers everywhere in trying to do this. I will just ask another question that has the actual code.

Thank you!

Comment: You should edit your question, asking the same question again but with more details will be seen as spam by the antispam system, and just clutters the site